# Nuxt - custom assets folders

Tags: nuxt.js

If I change the assets folder to some non-standard location, I cannot access them

```
url('~/theme/dark/assets/fonts/some-font.woff')
```

This gives me

```
These dependencies were not found:
```

How can I add other assets locations to my nuxt configuration?

Comment: Hi, try removing the / so you end up with ~/theme/.... the documentation states that's how you should be doing it

Comment: I already tried '~/theme...', '~theme...', '@/theme...'